# Can I differentiate between typeclass instances at runtime?

Tags: haskell, type-level-computation

Is it possible to implement a type class as follows:

```
class SomeClass e where
    isEq :: (SomeClass e') => e -> e' -> Bool
```

where `isEq x y` would return true when `x` and `y` are both the same instance of this type class?

Context: This is a thinly-veiled attempt at getting run-time type tests. While at first I read that Haskell has type erasure, I've also read that with recent extensions to GHC, some run-time information in there.

edit: for those wondering about my usecase... I've been using type-level programming to ensure certain properties of some of my ADTs, namely involving resource usage. These resources are represented by distinct types (and resource locks are accordingly implemented at type level).

I'm attempting to write an optimisation procedure that requires identification of resource writing/reading. But since all my resources are represented by distinct singletons, whose only common factor (apart from all values being bottom) is the typeclass which groupes them together.

In a nutshell I want to use the results of my type-level programming at a run-time, value level.

Comment: Are you aware of [Data.Typeable](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Typeable.html)? Seems relevant...

Comment: The question is misleading.  You seem to want, and the answers provide, a way to differentiate types at runtime.  I am interested in the other question: can one enumerate the classes inhabited by a particular type at run time.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson There is no quantification on typeclasses (i.e. there is no typeclass variables in haskell), so it is unlikely.

Comment: @permeakra Don't be too hasty to answer, it is clearly possible with hint (interpreting or JIT compilation of Haskell gives the the effect of run-time knowledge).  The question is more: is there an even better way than the horrible hack that we already know?

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Ok, let me say it this way: compiled modules do not contain such info. Typeclass instances are passed as dictionaries at runtime.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do this, as hinted at by Karolis Juodelė, with `Data.Typeable`:

```
Prelude Data.Typeable> :{
Prelude Data.Typeable| let isEq :: (Typeable a , Typeable b) => a -> b -> Bool
Prelude Data.Typeable|     isEq x y = typeOf x == typeOf y
Prelude Data.Typeable| :}
Prelude Data.Typeable> isEq True ()
False
Prelude Data.Typeable> isEq True False
True
```

The question is: Why would you not know at run time what the types are, and then why would you care about whether they are equal – can you elaborate your use case?

Comment: whoa! I didn't know about `:{ :}` syntax of ghci, it's great :D

Comment: "Why would you not know at run time what the types are, and why would you care about whether they are equal?" - Very good question. +1